# Warnings in TensorFlow while using MTCNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a project do detect faces and I'm using the following code:

```
# demonstrate face detection on 5 Celebrity Faces Dataset
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN

# extract a single face from a given photograph
def extract_face(filename, required_size=(160, 160)):
    # load image from file
    image = Image.open(filename)
    # convert to RGB, if needed
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    # convert to array
    pixels = asarray(image)
    # create the detector, using default weights
    detector = MTCNN()
    # detect faces in the image
    results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
    # extract the bounding box from the first face
    x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']
    # bug fix
    x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
    # extract the face
    face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    # resize pixels to the model size
    image = Image.fromarray(face)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    face_array = asarray(image)
    return face_array

# specify folder to plot
#folder = '5-celebrity-faces-dataset/train/ben_afflek/'
folder = '/content/drive/My Drive/ufc-project/5-celebrity-faces-dataset/train/ben_afflek'
i = 1
# enumerate files
for filename in listdir(folder):
    # path
    path = folder + '/' + filename
    # get face
    face = extract_face(path)
    print(i, face.shape)
    # plot
    pyplot.subplot(2, 7, i)
    pyplot.axis('off')
    pyplot.imshow(face)
    i += 1
pyplot.show()
```

I got this code from this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/?unapproved=549711&moderation-hash=6b355b586de2f2ff191df14529849990#comment-549711

It's working, but I'm getting the following warning:

`WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x7f0016e2eae8> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more details.`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the detector each time you call extract face. Move the face detector creation out from the loop and pass it as an argument to the function.
Move the line detector = MTCNN() outside of extract_face specifically before the loop.